# How to check existing options for an attribute in database from script in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I need to import color options to a Color Attribute via script. I need to to check existing options which is already exists in database and update new options via script. (I am using phpMyAdmin)

Answer (score 2):

Table logic is set this way:

1. Find ID of your attribute in `eav_attribute` table. For instance, Color has `attribute_id = 93`
2. Filter `eav_attribute_option` by `attribute_id = 93` and you will get `option_id`.
3. Check an option value in table `eav_attribute_option_value`